# difference between ruby regex and javascript regex

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I made this regular expression:  `/.net.(\w*)/`

I'm trying to capture the `qa` in a string like this:
`https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/qa/club/Slide1.PNG`

I'm doing `.replace` on it like so `location.replace(/.net.(\w*)/,data.newName));`

But instead of capturing `qa`, it captures `.net`, when I run the code in Javascript

According to this online regex tool made for ruby, it captures `qa` as intended

http://rubular.com/r/ItrG7BRNRn

What's the difference between Javascript regexes and Ruby regexes, and how can I make my regex work as intended in javascript?

### Edit:

I changed my code to this:

```
var str = `https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/qa/club`;
var re = /\.net\/([^\/]*)\//;
console.log(data2.files[i].location.replace(re,'$1'+ "test"));
```

And instead of

`https://dm7svtk8jb00c.cloudfront.net/test/club`

I get this:

`https://dm7svtk8jb00c.cloudfrontqatestclub`

If I remove the `$1` I get `https://dm7svtk8jb00c.cloudfronttestclub`, which is closer, but I want to keep the slashes.

Comment: Do you want the result to run in Ruby, or in JavaScript? `location` could be a variable in either language.

Comment: @theTinMan Javascript, sorry

Comment: BTW, if you want to test regex in JavaScript, I'd recommend http://regexpal.com/ or just use your Browser's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how Ruby works, but JavaScript replace will not just replace the capture group, it replaces the whole matched string. By adding another capture group, you can use $1 to add back in the string you want to keep.

```
...replace(/(.net.)(\w*)/,"$1" + data.newName");
```

Comment: I changed my regex to the one that Jon suggested, and moving the capture group around makes some small changes, but I'm not getting the result that I want

Comment: Well Jon only has one capture group around the content you want to remove, so of course it does not work.

Comment: I made another capture group around `(\.net\/)` and it worked. I don't think I like capture groups very much.

Comment: I actually asked the wrong question. I actually wanted to capture one more level further, so `club`, not `qa`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a better regex:

```
/\.net\/([^\/]*)\//
```

Remember that `.` will match any character, not the period character. For that you need to escape it with a leading backslash: `\.`

Also, `\w` will only match numbers, letters and underscores. You could quite legitimately have a dash in that part of the URL. Therefore you're far better off matching anything that isn't a forward slash.

Comment: I changed my regex to the one that you provided, but it seems to remove the `/` characters from my string. I want to keep those

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that like this:

```
location.replace(/(\.net.)(\w*)/, '$1' + data.newName)
```

`replace` replaces the whole matched substring, not a particular group. Ruby works exactly in the same way:

```
ruby -e "puts 'https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/qa/club/Slide1.PNG'.sub(/.net.(\w*)/, '@@')"
https://xxxxxx.cloudfront@@/club/Slide1.PNG

ruby -e "puts 'https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/qa/club/Slide1.PNG'.sub(/(.net.)(\w*)/, '\\1' + '@@')"
https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/@@/club/Slide1.PNG
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference (at least with the pattern you've provided). In both cases, the expression *matches* `".net/qa"`, with `qa` being the first *capture group* within the expression. Notice that even in your linked example the entire match is highlighted.

I'd recommend something like this:

```
location.replace(/(.net.)\w*/, "$1" + data.newName);
```

Or this, to be a bit safer:

```
location.replace(/(.net.)\w*/, function(m, a) { return a + data.newName; });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much a different between JavaScript and Ruby's implementations of regular expressions, it's your pattern that needs a bit of work. It's not tight enough.

You can use something like `/\.net\/([^\/]+)/`, which you can [see in action at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/5UOffEfvWo).
That returns the characters delimited by `/` following `.net`.

Regex patterns are very powerful, but they're also fraught with dangerous side-effects that open up big holes easily, causing false-positives, which can ruin results unexpectedly. Until you know them well, start simply, and test them every imaginable way. And, once you think you know them well, keep doing that; Patterns in code we write where I work are a particular hot-button for me, and I'm always finding holes in them in our code-reviews and requiring them to be tightened until they do exactly what the developer meant, not what they thought they meant.

While the pattern above works, I'd probably do it a bit differently in Ruby. Using the tools made for the job:

```
require 'uri'

URL = 'https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/qa/club/Slide1.PNG'
uri = URI.parse(URL)
path = uri.path # => "/qa/club/Slide1.PNG"
path.split('/')[1] # => "qa"
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
URI.parse(URL).path.split('/')[1] # => "qa"
```